# Displaying response on page after ajax call

Tags: php

This is my second day with php and still learning with jQuery/ajax. Don't laugh.

I have this code which passes an email address to a php page.

```
jQuery.getJSON("get-alert.php?returnformat=json",{"email":email},function(res,code){
            /*if(res == whatever){
                jQuery("#resSend").show();
            }*/
        });
```

The php script (shortened for clarity):

```
if(!$mail) {
                echo "Error sending email";
            } else {
                echo "Successfully sent, thank you for your interest!";
            }
```

The div which I want to show onSuccess looks like this:

```
<div id="resSend" class="opq2" style="display:none">Successfully sent. Thank you for your interest!</div>
```

What I don't understand is how to take the "succesfully sent" message from the php script and display it on the calling page rather than unhiding a div.

Comment: That's not JSON.

Comment: I know. I use getJSON for everything and it does work. Suggest some other way then pls

Comment: If you don't want to get JSON, don't call `getJSON`.  Did you see `$.ajax()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try returning a JSON instead of string

```
if(!$mail) {
                exit('{"result":"Error..."}');
            } else {
                exit('{"result":"Success..."}');
            }
```

Comment: Thanks, that was what I needed.